# A curve has the equation $y=(2x-3)^2$. Continue in description!

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the normal to the curve that is perpendicular to the straight line $4x-y-5=0$

WORKING: I'm not sure if I am doing it right because I don't even understand the question. >.< Here's my working, from the equation I get the gradient in which $m=4$, since it's normal to the curve the $m' = -1/4$ ?? Then what's next? I'm stuck here! >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's perpendicular to $y = 4x-5$, the solution should be of the form $y = -\frac{1}{4}x+b$. But since this is normal to the curve $y = (2x-3)^2$, you should differentiate this curve and find where its gradient is equal to 4, because the normal will pass through this point.

Comment: Sorry sir but I don't really understand the " you should differentiate this curve and find where its gradient is equal to 4, because the normal will pass through this point. " If it's not too forward of me, can you please explain further?

Comment: Are you familiar with differentiation? If you differentiate the curve $y = (2x-3)^2$ you will find the gradient of this curve for any value x. This will met you find out whete this curve has a gradient of 4. This will give be a point on the curve, $(x_0,y_0)$ and the normal will pass through this point. This means $y_0 = -\frac{1}{4} \times x_0 +b$, which gives you the b.